# Creating Array Elements through Read-Host, how can I move an element to another ArrayList using a situational array variable?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am very new to scripting but I could not find an answer to this question anywhere. It may be because I do not know the right terms to use to phrase the question. Please forgive my inexperience and bear with me..

At the beginning of my script I  create an array of computer names based on user input:

```
$computerarray = @()
do {
 $ComputerName = (Read-Host "Please enter the computer name")
 if ($Computername -ne '') {$computerarray += $Computername}
}
until ($Computername -eq '')
```

I use the array variables throughout the script in foreach loops using the $ComputerName variable to call each array element.

After I define the $computerarray, I then Test-Connection for each of them to determine which hosts are online, and my goal is to get rid of the hosts that are not able to connect. After some research I discovered that normal array elements cannot be deleted, but ArrayLists can be modified and allow elements to move to another array.

After learning this, I modify my initial code to set set $computerarray as an arraylist:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$computerarray = @()
do {
 $ComputerName = (Read-Host "Please enter the computer name")
 if ($Computername -ne '') {$computerarray += $Computername}
}
until ($Computername -eq '')
```

Then Create another array list to move the hosts that are not connecting,

```
$ComputersToDelete = @()
```

Then run the Test-Connection block:

```
foreach ($Computername in $computerarray) 
{
  If (Test-Connection -computername $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
      Write-Host "`nConnected to $Computername"
    } 
      Else 
        {
         Write-Host "`nCannot connect to $Computername" -forgroundcolor white -BackgroundColor red
```

In the else portion of that last block, I attempt to move the selected $ComputerName to the $ComputersToDelete array here:

```
$ComputersToDelete += $computerarray.$Computername
```

And lastly, I follow this block with:

```
foreach ($ComputersToDelete in $ComputersToDelete) {
  $ComputersToDelete.Delete()
}
```

I have read that to move an array element, it would go something like:

```
$ComputersToDelete += $computerarray[1]
```

However, since I'm only referencing the element with $ComputerNames, it does not seem to work. I want to remove the hosts that are not connection so the rest of the script does not waste time trying to connect to them each time.

Thanks for your future answers and I'm glad to finally be a part of the community!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to split the array into those that can and can't connect:

```
$Computers = $computerArray |Group-Object { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } -AsHashtable

$ToKeep    = $Computers[$true]
$ToDelete  = $Computers[$false]
```

Or (in PowerShell 4.0 and newer), use the `.Where()` method in `Split` mode:

```
$ToKeep,$ToDelete = $computerArray.Where({Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet},'Split')
```

Comment: I had no idea the v4 features had "modes"!  Where is the doc for that?